# Rails save form data for query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Thanks to the first two comments for the help.  Below is the fixed code for the search bar:

```
class TextbooksController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
    def index
        @textbooks = Textbook.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

I want users to search from the homepage, so I have a simple text field and submit button in the view:

```
<%= form_tag textbooks_path, method: "get" do %>
        <p>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, id: "search_btn_home" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search_bar_home", class: "form-control" %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

The textbooks index page is shown below

```
<% provide(:title, 'Search results') %>
<h1>Search results</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="textbooks">
    <%= render @textbooks %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Comment: You're just linking to `textbooks_path`, so you don't get anything from your search field there. You have to put the `text_field_tag` in a form and submit the form to `textbook_path`. Only then will you be able to use `params[:search]`.

Comment: <% form_tag to <%= form_tag ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I edited with what I thought would be the right code, but the form isn't being rendered at all now.  It doesn't look syntactically wrong to me though :/

Comment: Thanks juanitofatas, it was that =.  Can you explain why this works then? http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

Comment: Probably in old version of Rails, it uses rhtml, rhtml works that way. But now erb does not work this way anymore.